# How do I clear this array list after use?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

For example -

```
class Explorer {

     private List <File> all_files = new ArrayList <File> ();

    File [] explore (...) {
        ....
    } // this function returns, after modification, 
      // the all_files variable declared above.
      // Note :- this function is recursive.
}
```

I create an object of `Explorer` class and call the `explore` method, for the first call this causes no issues at all and I get what I expect. But if I try to use the same object the next time in a similar manner, well, you can already expect what is going to happen. Basically, the `explore` method appends some files at the end of `all_files` and returns it (as an array). Calling the method second times appends more files without clearing the `all_files` first.

So, I am looking for a strategy which would clear the `all_files` after one usage. I can not just add a statement like clear (all_files) at the end of my method because it is recursive and `all_files` is global. I want this cleaning process to be automatic, if possible. I.e., somehow my program should clear it when the entire recursion is complete (how to detect?). Suggest strategies.

EDIT : here is the entire code (uncommented) for those who are curious and skeptic of my strategy -

```
public class Explorer {   
    private List <File> all_files = new ArrayList <File> ();
    private int current_index = 0;

    public int depth_index;

    Explorer () { depth_index = Integer.MAX_VALUE; }
    Explorer (int index) { depth_index = index; }

    public File[] explore (String path) {

        if (++current_index > depth_index) {
            return all_files.toArray(new File[0]);
        }

        File f = new File (path);
        File[] dir_files = f.listFiles();

        for (File file : dir_files) {
            if (file.isFile())
                all_files.add(file);
            else
                explore (file.getPath());
        }

        current_index --;
        return all_files.toArray(new File[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't maintain the list outside of the local context of the method ... as an idea

Comment: I would have to change the entire code because of how it works, because the method is recursive and it appends recursively.

Comment: @Sarthak123 sometimes it's better to hold your nose and fix the problem than to look for ways to work around it.

Comment: And...........?

Comment: "this function returns the all_files variable declared above." No, it doesn't. This method returns an array, not a list.

Comment: it returns the array backed by that list using List.toArray (T[] a) standard java method

Comment: @Sarthak123 can you provide an extract of the recursive code?

Comment: ok I will edit the quesion to include the entire code.

Comment: The thing I'm most skeptical about is that you're not using [the API for walking the file tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Comment: Why do you have `all_files`, is it not enough just to return `File[]`?

Comment: @Andy Turner Because I have not learnt it yet. I have just been introduced to I/O and as an exercise I was trying to build a file explorer out of what I have learnt (I am NOT coding this as a replacement for java libraries). I encountered a issue (which is not even related to I/O) which I though is interesting so I asked here (and learned it).

Comment: @oleg.cherednik because I wanted to make the returned list as un-modifiable as possible and arrays was closest I could get to + it is less verbose this way. Why does it matter anyway? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Sarthak123 The do use `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the `List` in recursive invocations, pass it in recursive invocations:

```
class Explorer {

    File[] explore (...) {
        return explore(..., new ArrayList<>());
    }

    private File[] explore(..., List<File> all_files) {
      // Stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that *all* of your recursion state should be passed as parameters. For example, you have a bug in your code above where you aren't resetting `current_index` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not have to keep `all_files` in this class and worry about clear it. If you really need an array, then it is easy to transform collection to array. If you need unmodifiable colleciton (just like array), just decorate it with `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` (this is for `Set`, but there're other decorators for other collections there):

```
final class Explorer {

    public final int depth;

    Explorer() {
        this(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    Explorer(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    private static final File[] EMPTY = new File[0];

    public File[] explore(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        file = file.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
        Set<File> files = addFiles(file, 0, new TreeSet<>());

        return files.isEmpty() ? EMPTY : files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
    }

    private Set<File> addFiles(File dir, int depth, Set<File> files) {
        if (depth > this.depth)
            return files;

        File[] dirFiles = dir != null ? dir.listFiles() : null;

        if (dirFiles == null || dirFiles.length == 0)
            return files;

        for (File file : dirFiles) {
            if (file.isFile())
                files.add(file);
            else
                addFiles(file, depth + 1, files);
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am not convinced by your argument of using un-modifiable set (which increases complexity of code). I am using arrays because they are simple and less verbose and even the standard java libraries use arrays as return type in such cases. The only drawback being arrays allow change to members, but I think that is something the end user to take care of.

Comment: @Sarthak123 Well, this is your question and I have modified with `File[]`. But I really do not agree that using collections or smth. like that is decrease performance. Believe me, this is NOTHING according to other particular problems in the enterprise application (I believe, that you do not talk about high-performance trading application - this is completely another song). :-)